# Can you spawn a process in a shell script?

Tags: sh

I'm trying to get my #!/bin/sh shell script to start another application without pausing execution. That is I'm looking for a way to launch it in the background and have my shell script keep executing. I want it to work something like this:

```
# start daemon
start(){
success=`launch '/path/to/daemon'`
if [ $success != false ];then
echo 'daemon is now running'
fi
```

I'm also new to shell scripting so will the above (if launch existed) get the *return* of launch or the *stdout* set as $success?

I want to only use SH not BASH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use '&' sign after program name to launch it in background.
[Putting a program in the background](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0080.php)

Comment: Thank you, but why does STDOUT still go to the terminal window? is there any way to disable that?

Comment: I'm trying to have a fully independent process, this is a server daemon process and I don't want it's stdout anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

use NOHUP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup and send output to log using >> mylogfilename