# Trying to send cURL in BASH more times

Tags: bash, curl

i have this BASH script

```
for I in {1..15}; do curl ..here will be curl.. ; done
```

For send cURL every 1500ms and 15x
but it is not 1500ms,and i do not know how to edit it for it,
what im doing bad ?

Answer (score 3):

I order to execute some command every x seconds/milliseconds you must somehow delay your loop. Using `sleep` is easiest way to do it:

```
for I in {1..15}
do
  # non-blocking curl command here
  sleep 1.5
done
```

As default curl command will block execution of loop and times between each loop iteration will be longer and not even. To overcome this you need to prepare curl command that will be non-blocking.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Jans answer, you can make the curl run in the background by putting an '&' sign at the end. [Can you spawn a process in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133396/can-you-spawn-a-process-in-a-shell-script)

The result script would then be:

```
for I in {1..15}
do
  curl stackoverflow.com &
  sleep 1.5
done
```

It might be worth directing the output to separate files because you may get overlapping outputs if one curl command takes longer than 1.5 seconds.